# how to replace the text line with empty line

Tags: xml, bash, sed, grep

cat fxmgr/wrapperwin32.xml | sed '//d' | sed '//d' > cleaned.xml

This will remove the comments from the xml file but I want to replace the comments with the empty lines because I dont want to disturb the other code line numbers.

ex:

```
line one
xml comment
xml comment
line four
```

## output:

```
line one

line four
```

Assume 2 and 3 have the xml comments in the code. we just remove those lines and maintain the empty line.
I am not able to add the exact xml comments here.So hope the above ex clarifies it.

Real Example as presented in comments:

```
1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
2 <!---Students grades are uploaded by months----> 
3 <class_list> 
4 <student> 
5 <name>Tanmay</name> 
6 <grade>A</grade> 
7 </student> 
8 </class_list>
```

output

```
1 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
2 
3 <class_list> 
4 <student> 
5 <name>Tanmay</name> 
6 <grade>A</grade> 
7 </student> 
8 </class_list
```

Target : Replace contents of comment line 2 with spaces (and every other comment line in xml file similar to line 2)

Comment: would you mind providing some example input text and desired output ?

Comment: 1<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
2<!---Students grades are uploaded by months---->
3<class_list>
4   <student>
5      <name>Tanmay</name>
6      <grade>A</grade>
7   </student>
8</class_list>

output
=====
1<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
2
3<class_list>
4   <student>
5      <name>Tanmay</name>
6      <grade>A</grade>
7   </student>
8</class_list>

Comment: 1<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
2<!---Students grades are uploaded by months---->
3<class_list>
4   <student>
5      <name>Tanmay</name>
6      <grade>A</grade>
7   </student>
8</class_list>

output
=====
1<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
2
3<class_list>
4   <student>
5      <name>Tanmay</name>
6      <grade>A</grade>
7   </student>
8</class_list>

Comment: Please add this in question. It's hardly comprehensible

Comment: I added in the question.

Comment: assume line numbers are also not there

Comment: try `sed 's/xml.*//' file` let us know if it helps.

Comment: I still see "<--- " at comment line

Answer (score 1):

To replace comment lines of your xml file that according your comment have this format:

```
2 <!---Students grades are uploaded by months---->
```

You can use

```
sed 's/<!--.*-->/ /g' test.xml
```

`s/` : replace operation for sed (format 's/oldtext/newtext/g')
Tip : As newtext we just put a single space.

`/g` : is used for global replacement of all lines.

You can apply changes to the same file using `sed -i` , or you can redirect the output to another file by appending `>newfile.xml` in the end of the sed command.

Answer (score 0):

From googling I got that.

This is the command which deletes the commented lines in the XML file.

```
cat fxmgr/wrapperwin32.xml | sed '/<!--.*-->/d' | sed '/<!--/,/-->/d' > cleaned.xml
```

But I want to replace this comments with empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

try this to find and delete with with regular expression pattern matching.

```
cat fxmgr/wrapperwin32.xml | sed '/\/\//d' > cleaned.xml
```